# confluent schema registry dividing backend storage Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

confluent schema registry underlying store all the schemas under _schema topic in Kafka. Is it possible to split this backend storage topic into multiples like _schema1 and _schema2?

Why because in my production use case I want to store more than 1000 schemas, so separating the backend storage make the load on the topic will be less.

And, Does the confluent schema registry support backend storage other than Kafka topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to split, no; at work we have far more than 1000 schemas, and the registry works fine.

"Topic load" isn't the problem you're going to run into, it's heap usage of the registry server since schemas are stored across several Hashmaps

The backend store for the Confluent Registry is not overridable via config; you'd have to fork the code, swap out the KafkaStore interface, then recompile (haven't done it, but looked over the source enough to get the general concept).